# IPv6 Network performance on FreeBSD

Tags: performance, sockets, network-programming, freebsd, ipv6

I'd be interested to know what is the typical performance impact on using IPv6 network connections over IPv4. I plan to measure this myself, but wanted to check if someone has already done some analysis on **FreeBSD**. Basically things like:

- Socket creation time/overhead. Is it same as IPv4
- Connection speed/latency of a TCP packet over IPv6 vs IPv4.

There seems to be a general agreement that IPv6 is slower, but I'm not sure by what magnitude.
Also any specific IPv6 specific tuning that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much specific to FreeBSD about the actual topic.  IPv6 sockets will take the same startup time as any other socket and the performance is related to the network infrastructure.

At basic IP header analysis you are talking about 20 extra bytes per packet for IPv6, which translates to ~1% at gigabit line speeds.  IPv6 is supposed to route faster than IPv4 as it is less complex, but read the performance reports on Cisco, in particular dual stack networking infrastructure for more limitations on *todays* real world achievable values:

http://www.cisco.com/web/strategy/docs/gov/IPv6perf_wp1f.pdf